# Can you update a field for all records from external source?

Tags: cognito-forms

Can you update a field for all records from external source?

For example, I set up a form so it has the Reference #, Person's Name, $'s, and What to buy - users are sent the link so they can edit the what to buy field whenever desired based on the $'s available.

The $'s available would be maintained in an Excel file offline and so is there a way to create a file from the Excel file with Reference # and $'s and then auto update the $'s field in each of the appropriate records based on the reference#?

Comment: Interesting. Cognito-forms. Neat idea. I'm glad I stopped by and learned about some new technology. Does this system accept payment and deposit the money for you? Cool. I'd have to guess since it's a proprietary form on their server that you'd have no way to FTP into their server to update your Excel sheet to be read from the sheet that lives on their server. The way you explained it the Excel file is offline, but you would have to manually move that file on every update. I'd look into setting up a database using MySQL and keep it alive and dynamic. Excel also needs ODBC API experience.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not offer the ability to update or pull data out of an external source. This is a feature that we are looking into and you can follow along with our progress over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/sgDIKA7o).